# Why is 1H-pyrrol-1-ium non-aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image: 1H-pyrrol-1-ium]

It has 4n electrons and is completely conjugated. It should be anti aromatic.

Why is this compound non-aromatic?

Comment: Pyrrole is aromatic because it has six electrons in its conjugated $\pi$ system. This thing has four.

Comment: @IvanNeretin This thing has 4 electrons, so it must be anti aromatic. Why it is non aromatic?

Comment: Why should it be antiaromatic? It does not even have a **cyclic** conjugated $\pi$ system anymore.

Comment: Not fully conjugated.  There is a saturated atom in the cycle.

Answer (score 3):

It is non-aromatic even though it has 4$\pi$ electrons because nitrogen cannot form five bonds. Hence delocalisation is not possible and so it is non aromatic.